# docopt module is never found eventhough install

Tags: linux

I am trying to run a simple command line that requires dependencies module.
I have installed the dependencies
pip install requests docopt
ran the script -> ./generate-dnscrypt-cmdline. Everytime i get
ImportError: No module named 'docopt'
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docopt in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
any idea ?
PS: I am using Fedora 23

Finally found the problem. For those trying to use a module in fedora 23 that is installed and getting "import error", write this line in your .bashrc

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

restart your terminal and you should be good to go.

Comment: `# dnf install python-docopt` .... Alternatively `# pip install docopt` ...  https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=docopt&submit=search

Comment: thanks for your reply but as i have already installed docopt. My problem lies where it is never found on my system.